# How to choose repository implementation dynamically in spring 3

Tags: java, spring

I have an Repository layer and It has two implementations. Currently I am switching between them using Qualifier annotation but I want to do this based on a property file which is outside the project. So if I change that property and restart application, it should pic that repository. How can we do this in Spring 3.

Comment: Take a look at [Spring profiles](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-profiles.html)

Answer (score 2):

Use Profile(spring 3.1) https://spring.io/blog/2011/02/14/spring-3-1-m1-introducing-profile/

```
@Autowired
private MyRepoInterface repo;
```

In the context:

```
@Bean
@Profile("prod")
public MyRepoInterface repo1() {
    return new RepoImpl1();
}

@Bean
@Profile("dev")
public MyRepoInterface repo2() {
    return new RepoImpl2();
}
```

If the active profile is prod - only the repo1 bean will be created and injected.

Answer (score 0):

Load your properties file into the context:

```
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:app.properties" />
```

Use the Spring Expression Language (SpEL) ternary operator:

```
<bean name="serviceX" > 
    <property name="repo" value="#{ ${useDefaultRepo} == 'true' ? efaultRepoRef : otherRepoRef }" />
</bean>
```